# Is it once-great or once great in the context of something of declining or former glory or status?

Tags: vocabulary, orthography

I am writing a story. A peer gave me the suggestion to change the "once great" to "once-great". Here is the sentence:

> He was tall and his body frame showed the signs of stoutness of once great youth.

Comment: That's right. _once-great_ is a compound adjective modifying the noun _youth._ And compound adjectives are hyphenated. It's further suggested that you write _a once-great_ youth.

Comment: If you look for examples on the internet, you will find both the hyphenated and open forms of the compound adjective [once great]. As far as I can see, neither variant is rare, though perhaps the open form is more popular ... probably reflecting the general trend towards using more minimalistic punctuation. [Adv + Adj]-form compound adjectives are probably more usually open **except** where confusion might arise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Now forgotten" vs. "now-forgotten", "once powerful" vs. "once-powerful"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341670/now-forgotten-vs-now-forgotten-once-powerful-vs-once-powerful) For other particular examples, research should rapidly clarify usage.

Comment: @

@Michael Harvey 'Minimalist punctuation' is a known expression; 'more minimalistic' connotes this school strongly, while 'less punctuation' sounds (and in practice may well be) crude. I've chosen the wording so as to endorse my belief that many traditional commas, hyphens, and certainly colons can advantageously be ditched. Dispensed with. Consigned to history.

Comment: How is it better than e.g. 'a ... trend towards using less [or minimal] punctuation'? H ave to say that I agree with the notion one hundred percent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorter_Oxford_English_Dictionary: 16 000 words lost their hyphen (sixth and latest edition of the SOED)